# Selenium Java Firefox driver - Cookies

Tags: java, cookies, selenium

How can I save all cookies in java's selenium webdriver to a txt file, then load them later? The documentation doesn't say much of anything about the addCookie function.

I've tried it in a multitude of ways and none seem to work at all.

I can get selenium to show me/save the cookies to a file its just loading them mainly that is the problem....

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3):

I think the most important part is to fetch Cookies:

```
webDriver.manage().getCookies();
```

Return type is `Set<Cookies>`. With this you can build your own logic for reading and writing to file. 
Maybe you prefer some library for serialization. I really like [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/).

Comment: I can get the cookies and save them to a .txt file. Its just loading the cookies for use instead of having to login to the site again.

Comment: How do you try to save them to txt file? What exactly goes wrong?